# create thumbs up icon using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a thumbs up icon something like (https://thenounproject.com/term/thumbs-up/70801/) with the html5 canvas commands (e.g. arc, arcto ...). I know about those functions but I have no idea how to get started to design that thumbs up icon.

The design should be split on a grid of 3 x 3 cells.

Canvas would be 300 x 300 and each cell in the canvas will be 100 x 100.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

    <script>
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        var rectX = 70;
        var rectY = 70;
        var rectWidth = 50;
        var rectHeight = 100;
        var cornerRadius = 10;

        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = cornerRadius;

        ctx.strokeRect(rectX+(cornerRadius/2), rectY+(cornerRadius/2), rectWidth-cornerRadius, rectHeight-cornerRadius);
    </script>
```

Above code creates the rounded sleeve of the thumbs up icon.

Can anyone help how to create such icon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Rounding corners.

To draw that shape you would need to round the corners of a path. The path being just a set of x and y coordinates as an array.

#### Beziers too ugly

Most solutions would involve using beziers, but I find them rather ugly as they never match the shape of a circle, and in the world of design, a circle must be the correct shape (round).

#### Arcs

The best solution is to render the path using the `ctx.arc` function and providing a start angle and end angle for each corner. This can be difficult to visualize in the mind, so it would be better to define the corners to have a radius and let the machine calculate the start and end arc angles for you.

Thus your path would have the x,y coords and a radius for each corner. A radius of 0 is not rounding. You would also need to create rounded corners at the end if the shape is closed and not if the shape is open.

Your shape data could look something like (not a thumbs up)

```
const shape = [
    {x : 10,  y : 10,  r : 20},    
    {x : 150, y : 10,  r : 50},    
    {x : 100, y : 100, r : 20},    
    {x : 50,  y : 100, r : 20},    
    {x : 50,  y : 200, r : 20},    
    {x : 210, y : 100, r : 60},    
    {x : 210, y : 300, r : 20},    
    {x : 10,  y : 300, r : 20},    
    "closed",
];
```

#### Rendering example

The rendering is complex, for each corner you need to find the center of the arc and the points on the incoming lines where the arc meets (the tangents). I am not going to explain the math here as I don't think you want that but the example has a step by step explanation if you are comfortable with vector math.

With some checking for valid solutions and providing a way to have open and closed paths (with open and close arcs at the ends) the following example should let you create the shape you want. (I will not plot the points, too lazy to do that)

**Example** draws two shapes, closed and open. The shape to the right also has a corner with no radius. It uses `ctx.lineJoin = "miter"` to ensure that the corner is sharp. Though you can round the outside edge by setting `ctx.lineJoin = "round"` and the radius of the outside rounding is equal to half the line width.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const shape = [
    {x : 10,  y : 10,  r : 20},    
    {x : 150, y : 10,  r : 50},    
    {x : 100, y : 100, r : 20},    
    {x : 50,  y : 100, r : 20},    
    {x : 50,  y : 200, r : 20},    
    {x : 210, y : 100, r : 60},    
    {x : 210, y : 300, r : 20},    
    {x : 10,  y : 300, r : 20},    
    "closed",
];
const shapeOpen = [
    {x : 390,  y : 10,  r : 0},    
    {x : 390,  y : 300, r : 50},    
    {x : 310,  y : 300, r : 20},    
    {x : 320,  y : 200, r : 0},    
    {x : 240,  y : 200, r : 40},   
    {x : 240,  y : 10,  r : 0},       
];

// round line ends
ctx.lineCap = "round";
// and sharp corners if no radius
ctx.lineJoin = "miter";

// draw closed and open shapes
drawRoundedShape(shape,12,"Black");
drawRoundedShape(shapeOpen,12,"Black");

function drawRoundedShape(shape, lineWidth, strokeStyle, fillStyle) {
    function roundCorner(p1, p2, p3, returnCorner = {}) {
        var x, y, v1x, v1y, v2x, v2y, leng, l1, cx, cy;
        
        // Convert lines to normalised vectors from p2
        v1x = p1.x - p2.x;
        v1y = p1.y - p2.y;
        v2x = p3.x - p2.x;
        v2y = p3.y - p2.y;
        leng = Math.sqrt(v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y);
        v1x /= leng; 
        v1y /= leng;
        leng = Math.sqrt(v2x * v2x + v2y * v2y);
        v2x /= leng; 
        v2y /= leng;
        
        // check directions
        const cross = (v1x * v2y - v1y * v2x); 
        
        // if near parallel then ignore as roundable.
        if(Math.abs(cross) < 1e-4){
            returnCorner.solutionFound = false;
            return returnCorner;
        }
        
        // set radius sign, arc direction to match corner
        const radius = p2.r * Math.sign(cross); 
        returnCorner.dir = radius > 0;
        returnCorner.solutionFound = true;

        // Get distance from p2 to circle tangent along line p2 - p1
        l1 = radius / cross; 
        l1 += l1 * (v1x * v2x + v1y * v2y);
    
        // Find tangent contact on line p2-p1
        x = p2.x + v1x * l1;
        y = p2.y + v1y * l1;        
        
        // Save first tangent point though not needed could come in handy
        returnCorner.t1x = x;
        returnCorner.t1y = y;

        // Find arc center
        cx = x - v1y * radius;
        cy = y + v1x * radius;
        
        // Find direction of arc start
        returnCorner.ang1 = Math.atan2(y - cy, x - cx);
        
        // Find tangent contact on line p2-p3
        x = p2.x + v2x * l1;
        y = p2.y + v2y * l1;        

        // Find direction of arc end
        returnCorner.ang2 = Math.atan2(y - cy, x - cx);
        
        // Save second tangent point 
        returnCorner.t2x = x;
        returnCorner.t2y = y;

        // Save arc center
        returnCorner.x = cx;
        returnCorner.y = cy;
        
        // Return the corner as an arc
        return returnCorner;
    }
    var corner, i, len, isClosed;
    len = shape.length;
    isClosed = false;
    if (typeof shape[len - 1] === "string" && shape[len - 1].toLowerCase() === "closed") {
        len -= 1;
        isClosed = true;
    }
    // shape must have 3 or more points
    if (len < 3) { return }

    // start rendering
    ctx.beginPath();
    i = 0;
    do {
        if (shape[i].r === 0) { // if the radius is 0 then just set the corner point
            ctx.lineTo(shape[i].x, shape[i].y);
        } else {
        
            // Calculate the corner arc details
            corner = roundCorner(
                shape[(i + len - 1) % len], 
                shape[i],
                shape[(i + 1) % len], 
                corner
            );
            
            // If a valid solution found render the arc
            if (corner.solutionFound) {  // only if there is a rounded corner
                ctx.arc(
                    corner.x,
                    corner.y,
                    shape[i].r,
                    corner.ang1,
                    corner.ang2,
                    corner.dir
                );
            } else {
                ctx.lineTo(shape[i].x, shape[i].y);  // no valid solution so just plot the point
            }
        }
    } while (++i < len);
    
    isClosed && ( ctx.closePath() );

    // The path has been created so fill and or stroke it
    if (fillStyle) {
        ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;    
        ctx.fill();
    }
    if (strokeStyle) {
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
        ctx.stroke();
    }    
}
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width = "400" height = "310"></canvas>
```

**Notes**

The code has only been tested on a small set of shapes, there could still be situations when the arc at a corner is placed on the wrong side. If this does happen the easy solution is just to add a flag to the corner point to reverse the direction and in the `roundCorner` function negate the radius if that flag is true.

Also as the path is precalculated, I did not see a need to limit the radius. That means if the radius results in the tangent being outside the lines segments coming into the corner the path will come back on itself after being drawn to the tangent. To fix just reduce the radius of the corner to fit.